# Can users delete comments they don't like?

Tags: support, deleted-comments

I was reading @kjhughes answer to this question: [XML Schema minOccurs / maxOccurs default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821477/xml-schema-minoccurs-maxoccurs-default-values)

Part of his answer made me LOL:  A is optional and must appear exactly once

This is impossible to be true and obviously wrong, so commented something like this:  "A is optional and must appear exactly once." LOL.  A truth that is mutually exclusive.

I say "something like this" because my comment is gone.  I can't find any record of it anywhere, yet I obviously made the comment because the user edited his answer to fix his mistake.

What happened to my comment?  Can users delete comments they don't like?

Comment: Mods can single-handedly delete comments, and often will if they are flagged by someone for one of the flag reasons given to comments. Some words will make the comment system-deletable for just from a flag.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if "LOL" was one of the keywords that make comments auto-deletable.

Comment: It was flagged as obsolete after the edit and it got deleted.

Comment: Also, since the user took your feedback into account and adjusted the answer, it would have been more than appropriate for them (or anyone else) to flag it as "obsolete".

Comment: We also hate fun...

Comment: Well, @JustDoIt's comment doesn't contain a naughty word that triggers immediate deletion.  Sorry, whoever handled that flag :)

Comment: Hmm, so you posted that comment with the *intention* of making the user not like it instead of helping to improve the post.  Well, lolz on you.

Comment: AFAIK: Moderators can delete a comment without any indication to the user.

Answer (score 8):

kjhughes [fixed the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33686479/4) to remove the incongruity that made you laugh. So your comment became "obsolete". It was probably flagged as such, and probably deleted on this basis. Comments are second class citizens. They need to have lasting value to avoid being deleted.